# Can weather expressions and other impersonal expressions be inverted?

Tags: grammaire, interrogative

*Il pleut, il neige, il fait froid, il fait beau, il faut,* etc. can such phrases be inverted? Are these legitimate sentences?

> Pleut-il? Neige-t-il? Fait-il froid? Fait-il beau? Me faut-il un crayon?

Even if it is grammatically allowed, is it natural/normal/common? Or very rare?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not only possible but is the canonical formal (or written) way to ask those questions; being a placeholder pronoun is not an obstacle to inversion. That said, it is *very* uncommon and would *sound* overly formal or charmingly old-fashioned in most contexts. So you are safe using them, but would probably get you spotted as a non-native speaker. The usual forms are built on “​*est-ce que*”

> *Est-ce qu'il pleut ?
>
>   Est-ce qu'il neige ?
>
>   Est-ce qu'il y a quelqu'un ?*

or even

> *Il pleut ?*

discarding *est-ce que* and relying on intonation to denote the interrogative nature.

But remember that this only applies to *oral* and that inversion is the canonical form for *writing*.

Comment: Would *Est-ce qu'il pleut?* sound sufficiently unnatural that it could in of itself alert someone that I was not a native speaker?

Comment: Nope, *“est-ce qu'il pleut ?”* is how almost everybody say it, but children in school are taught that the “proper form” is *“pleut-il ?”*.

Comment: @Evpok Indeed they are. I clearly remember being taught that.

Comment: @Evpok Waiiiitt--- so *"Y a-t-il..."* falls into this same category of being correct but unusual for speech, but preferred for writing?

Comment: @Aerovistae Yep.

Answer (score 6):

As a French, I would say that all these sentences sound (actually are) correct.

> Pleut-il ? Neige-t-il ? Fait-il froid ? Fait-il beau ? Me faut-il un crayon ?

as well as

> Est-ce qu'il pleut ? Est-ce qu'il neige ? etc.

I would personally rather use

> Est-ce qu'il me faut un crayon ?

than

> Me faut-il un crayon ?

when talking to somebody. But both are OK. The latter would sound more formal. The former is more casual.

Also, *dois-je prendre un crayon ?* could be more natural, but that's just a way of saying it.